# how to add http_proxy automatically to new users in ubuntu server

Tags: proxy

I have a headless ubuntu server and it is behind a proxy. I usually set the proxy manually using `export http_proxy=http://serverip:8080` . I want to know how / where can I set this so that every new user created on the server can use this proxy by default .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put that into `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh` to make it system-wide available for all users that login. The file pretty sure does not exists, so just create it.

You also could put that into `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, but that would only affect users that are newly created after making your changes. And this only affects users that are created locally, so this is error-prone.